# Selenium Webdriver: Updates on a application taking too long or timing out

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have an application where a Pop up is opened where you can change the person's information and click on Save will save the information. But however, its taking too long to save the page. Sometime, it timeout or other time takes too long to update. Is anyone facing the similar issue?

My script is simple.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).click();//opens the pop up
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).clear();//clear the text box
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendKeys("FirstName, LastName");//update the name
driver.findElement(By.id("click_on_save")).click();//click on save
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?I guess it means that your application is slow so it's not a `selenium` related problem...

Comment: Sorry for late reply. My application is not slow when I do it manually. But when I use webdriver, its taking forever or slow.

Comment: Can you provide more info?Which browser, OS are you using?Do you run it locally or through Jenkins or other CI?

Comment: My application only supports IE-8. I am using window OS. I run it locally right now.